# Does this unit distance graph with 137 vertices need five colors?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

in a German math forum we tried to color this unit distance graph with 4 colors, but can't do this. If you find a solution with 4 colors please show it.

[unit distance graph with 137 vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMTuq.png)

Thanks, Mike

Comment: How about an adjacency matrix? That picture is pretty but impossible to sort out for labeling purposes.

Comment: Give me a few hours to create. The graph has a rotational symmetry of order 3. Here is one of our attempts: [link](http://www.matheplanet.de/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?topic=216644&post_id=1717500)

Comment: ok, we find a solution with 4 colors.

Comment: Too bad. It would have been a nice improvement.

Comment: Now we have the same problem after adding a few new vertices, so it remains exciting. ;-) Take a look in the link above.

Comment: Again some kind of reasonable representation other than a drawing would be nice.

Comment: An adjacency matrix needs a lot of work. I will do this if we can't find a 4 color solution during a few days. Here is an DXF file of the current graph with 193 vertices: [link](http://mikewinkler.co.nf/Winkler-Graph-193.dxf)

Comment: 4 color solution is found.